# Configuring virtual network interface as sniffing interface

Tags: networking, snort, sniffing

I have a Snort IDS running Ubuntu Server 16.04 with one physical ethernet interface (eno1). I have configured two virtual network interfaces using the eno1 interface: eno1:0 for the sniffing interface and eno1:1 for the management interface, which is configured with a static IP address. The problem I am experiencing is that only the management interface (eno1:1) is up, while the sniffing interface (eno1:0) is down as indicated in the below output of ifconfig:

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:34:6b:61:d1:b3
          inet6 addr: fe80::c634:6bff:ac61:d1b3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28019 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1046 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3471780 (3.4 MB)  TX bytes:116452 (116.4 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000

eno1:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:34:6b:61:d1:b3
          inet addr:192.168.1.154  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:12020 (12.0 KB)  TX bytes:12020 (12.0 KB)
```

Below are the settings for both the sniffing and management interfaces contained in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# sniffer interface
auto eno1:0

iface eno1:0 inet manual
        up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
        up ip link set $IFACE promisc on
        down ip link set $IFACE promisc off
        down ifconfig $IFACE down

post-up ethtool -K eno1:0 gro off
post-up ethtool -K eno1:0 lro off

# management interface
auto eno1:1

iface eno1:1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.154
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.2
        dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1
```

The configuration settings for the sniffing interface have been used from this [link](https://www.andrewhay.ca/archives/1144), but the sniffing interface does not go up. What could be the problem?

Comment: What happens if you bring the interface up manually, e.g. with `ifup`?